# How to change session_save_path in php.ini file?

Tags: session, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting on godaddy.

I tried to change session save path in php.ini file with this line,

```
sessions.save_path = "/session"
```

I've controlled the sessions save path with [sessions.save_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) function. It returns `/tmp` before and after changing `php.ini`

Is it possible to change session save path on shared hosting?
Where am I wrong?

Comment: its `session.save_path`, not plural sessions

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can modify the session save path on shared hosting by creating a custom php.ini.

Include this in your file: `session.save_path = "/path/to/your/folder"`

Otherwise, you can use:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/path/to/your/folder')
```

The folder you use should be under your domain/account but not accessible through a Web browser. It also needs to have world-writable permissions on it. And every page that uses sessions must include that line.

Comment: I tried both method, I have but session save path always return /tmp, It's not changing.

Comment: Note that "sessions.save_path" is incorrect as the commenter below notes--it should be "session.save_path". Once I removed the "s" and had session.save_path, it worked for me.

Comment: The correct syntax is `ini_set('session.save_path', '/path/to/your/folder')`

Answer (score 10):

It is `session.save_path` and not `sessions.save_path` (it may have been renamed or something, I don't know, but `sessions.save_path` did not work for me)

```
session.save_path = "/path/to/your/folder"
```

works fine

Answer (score 2):

It is also important to note that `session.save_path` must be called before `session_start()`

Answer (score 1):

Check other files, for example: `php_value[session.save_path]` in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
and webservers users should have rights..

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named session in the `C:\session.`

Change the `session.save_path();` directory to the newly created path: (`C:\session`) anywhere out of `tmp` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got sessions working, with help from this thread. I'm running PHP in IIS.

Set the session folder in php.ini.

```
session.save_path = "C:/inetpub/temp/php_session"
```

(I'm not yet sure if this session folder is best practice for my environment..security-wise. I need to do more reading on this.)

Setting the session path was not enough. At first, I had placed session_start() in a function where I needed to set my session variables but even though the session file was created in my path (sess_d9eeeb305928f2f39a25f296773b09eb), the $_SESSION value was lost during an ajax post to my PHP page. Someone on stack\o said to put session_start() as the first line, so I tried that and my session value is working. I haven't figured out where to destroy it.

```
<?php 
session_start();
...
```