# PHP Session Variables can not access some pages

Tags: php, session

I have a website that does not have subdomains. There is an issue with Session variables in the same domain name. Some pages can read session variables that are set in login but some pages can not read session variables.

I have done some research on this.

Let's take like this,

- X page - Session variable not getting page
- Y page - Session variable getting page

First I check the Session ID for both X and Y pages by following the code

```
<?php session_start();
echo session_id();
?>
```

Both pages give same value which is `b01af97b1c97c42ee4d6cef73b154c4e`.

After that, I check the Session file path and size by the following code.

```
<?php session_start();

$sessionfile = ini_get('session.save_path') . '/' . 'sess_'.session_id();  
echo 'session file: ', $sessionfile, ' ';  
echo 'size: ', filesize($sessionfile), "\n";

?>
```

I got different values.

For X page,

```
session file: /sess_b01af97b1c97c42ee4d6cef73b154c4e 
size:
```

For Y page,

```
session file: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72/sess_b01af97b1c97c42ee4d6cef73b154c4e 
size: 242
```

Then I check php.ini file by the following code.

```
<?php session_start();
phpinfo();
?>
```

X Page values:

```
session.cookie_path : /
session.save_path: no value
```

Y page values:

```
session.cookie_path : /
session.save_path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72
```

Why those values are different in the same domain name? How can I solve this error? I need to access  session variables in all pages of same domain.

Update:

I have changed session.save_path manually to `session.save_path = "/tem"` in php.ini. This is only updated in X page not updated in Y page. I cehck in both pages by phpinfo();. Why is that?

Page X php info.

[image]

Page Y php info

[image]

Comment: And the rest of the `phpinfo` output is the same (in all relevant parts)? Your two scripts are not perhaps executed using different PHP versions, or with different `php.ini` files getting used?

Comment: Try to use `session_save_path()` function instead

Comment: @CBroe other values sames. Check updated question

Comment: @AterLux Do you mean set file path by session_save_path() before session_start() ?

Comment: @CBroe I am use shared hosting service and it is the same php.ini I guess and the same PHP version.

Comment: Check file ownership if you're on a Linux box. One script may be owned by root and another by a user. You can also edit php.ini to set session path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927404/how-to-change-session-save-path-in-php-ini-file#8929262

Comment: @MisterG13 I change it to session.save_path = "/tmp" in php.ini but it show in X page not show in Y page. Why is that? Same domain same sharehosting.

Comment: Go to this link and read it over. Use the exec whoami or get current user functions on each page to find file ownership. Please report results, ideally they should have same owner on both pages but in your case, probably not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548743/php-get-current-user-vs-execwhoami#28549300